# Fitting binomial GLMM to unbalanced data with glmer (lme4) in R. When is data too unbalanced?

Tags: r, logistic-regression, lme4, mixed-models

I'm trying to model data from a repeated measures experiment where the response variable is a bernoulli response (i.e., 0 vs. 1; error vs. correct reponse). I'm using the `glmer` function (R package `lme4`)  with `family = binomial` to fit a logistic model looking at how two independent variables (i.e., `Trial_Type` and `Block`) influence the probability of committing an error in a given trial. The key manipulation here ist that one particular trial type is presented more often than the other ones. This is meant to "lure" participants into committing errors in the other trials.

This is how the data look like:

```
'data.frame':   8212 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ ID              : Factor w/ 32 levels "data_1","data_10",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Block           : Factor w/ 2 levels "Block 1","Block 2": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Trial           : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ Trial_Type      : Factor w/ 4 levels "1","2","3",..: 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 3 1 1 ...
 $ RT              : int  336 430 430 309 253 386 275 339 368 469 ...
 $ Reaction        : Factor w/ 2 levels "Correct","Incorrect": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 ...
 $ Error_vs_Correct: num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 ...
```

And this is the model:

```
mod_bi_I <- glmer(Error_vs_Correct ~ Trial_Type + Block + Trial_Type:Block + (1|ID/Trial_Type), 
                family = binomial(link = 'logit'), data = all_data, 
                control = glmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa"))

car::Anova(mod_bi_I, type=3)

Analysis of Deviance Table (Type III Wald chisquare tests)

Response: Error_vs_Correct
                    Chisq Df Pr(>Chisq)    
(Intercept)      404.2388  1    < 2e-16 ***
Trial_Type       103.7184  3    < 2e-16 ***
Block              0.0924  1    0.76111    
Trial_Type:Block   6.6494  3    0.08395 .
```

My question is **1)** whether the unbalanced nature of the data might lead to inaccurate results while using the `glmer` approach? or **2)** whether nesting observations within trial types and individuals `(1|ID/Trial_Type)` will be able to handle it fine. I've read ([here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/230721/how-to-check-overdispersion-of-binomial-glmms-lme4-package), for instance) that some degree of "unbalancedness" should'nt be a problem, but I'm wondering how much is too much.

Here is a Cross Tab of observations by trial type and response:

```
          Error_vs_Correct
Trial_Type    0    1
        1    89 5646
        2    25  804
        3   140  672
        4    21  815
```

Comments will be most appreciated!

**EDIT:** I have stored a sample of the dataset [here](https://github.com/JoseAlanis/SampleData_BinomialGLMM/blob/master/SampleData.R) (ready for analysis) in case you'd like to recreate the model.

Comment: Could you please `dput` a sample of `all_data` and include in your question so that other may reproduce your example?

Comment: Hey @KevinArseneau, sure, I ran the `dput` on the dataset and included a link. Thanks for the hint